# Cookies in asp.net error

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, webmatrix

I am a newbie in asp.net I am trying to create a cookie in web matrix here is my code

```
 <%
        Response.Cookies("ssn") = StudentNumber
        Response.Cookies("ssn").Expires = Date + 365
%>
```

it shows an error at "%" why is that?
error message is

> Unknown element '%' or element cannot be placed here.

Thank you

Comment: damith's answer will be work if you have .cshtml format (consider from your comments) but you are doing it wrong if you write this aspx code in .cshtml file.

Comment: Please update your question with complete error text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *Response*, you can try *HttpContext.Current.Response*

```
<%
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies("ssn") = StudentNumber
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies("ssn").Expires = Date + 365
%>
```

**Edit**

```
@{
     Response.Cookies["ssn"].Value = StudentNumber;
     Response.Cookies["ssn"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
}
```

Comment: You need to create Date variable :) or: DateTime.Now.AddDays(365)

Answer (score 0):

[Cookie.Expires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.expires.aspx) is DateTime, I don't think there is any built in "+" operation that produces DateTime.

You probably want `= Date.AddDays(365)` (assuming Date is of type DateTime).

Or use ["+" that takes TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_addition):

```
Response.Cookies("ssn").Expires = Date + TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
```

Comment: Is their any difference adding a cookie in response and your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
        Response.Cookies("ssn") = StudentNumber;
        Response.Cookies("ssn").Expires =DateTime.Now;
}
```